# Can a touchscreen be used as a functional secondary in windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui, touchscreen

I have recently purchased windows 8, and unlike some I'm really enjoying the metro interface. I'd just like to know whether I can attach a second monitor, touchscreen enabled, and use that as a secondary. Ideally, I'd like the desktop displayed on one, with the metro on the other. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is possible.

**Charms->Devices->Second Screen**

[image]

Of course, for the **Second Screen** option to show up you'll need to have your secondary display attached.

Once you select **Second Screen** you'll be presented with four options

- PC Screen only
- Duplicate
- Extend
- Secondary screen only

For your case, you'll have to select **Extend**